# Remove new line in zsh theme

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to modify zsh theme af-magic. I really like it except one part. It makes a line full if dashes after every command.

I would out that this `{(l.COLUMNS..-.)}` part does that. If I remove the whole section, or `-` to make it `{(l.COLUMNS...)}`, it draws an empty line.
So I want to get rid of this empty line. I tried to find `\n` anywhere, but there are none.

So this is the theme

```
# af-magic.zsh-theme
# Repo: https://github.com/andyfleming/oh-my-zsh
# Direct Link: https://github.com/andyfleming/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/af-magic.zsh-theme

if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then NCOLOR="red"; else NCOLOR="green"; fi
local return_code="%(?..%{$fg[red]%}%? ↵%{$reset_color%})"

# primary prompt
PROMPT='$FG[237]${(l.COLUMNS..-.)}%{$reset_color%}
$FG[032]%~/\
$(git_prompt_info)$(hg_prompt_info)\
$FG[105]%(!.#.)%{$reset_color%}'
PROMPT2='%{$fg[red]%}\ %{$reset_color%}'
RPS1='${return_code}'


# color vars
eval my_gray='$FG[237]'
eval my_orange='$FG[214]'

# right prompt
if type "virtualenv_prompt_info" > /dev/null
then
    RPROMPT='$FG[078]$(virtualenv_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%} $my_gray%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%'
else
    RPROMPT='$my_gray%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%'
fi

# git settings
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="$FG[075]($FG[078]"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="$my_orange*%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="$FG[075])%{$reset_color%}"

# hg settings
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_PREFIX="$FG[075]($FG[078]"
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_DIRTY="$my_orange*%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_SUFFIX="$FG[075])%{$reset_color%}"
```

As a separate question, which language is this?

Comment: The language is `zsh`; the shell (like virtually all shells) is an interpreter for a particular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the use of `COLUMNS` from the prompt.

```
PROMPT='$FG[237]${(l.COLUMNS..-.)}%{$reset_color%}
$FG[032]%~/\
$(git_prompt_info)$(hg_prompt_info)\
$FG[105]%(!.#.)%{$reset_color%}'
```

Once you do that, you can also remove the code that colored the now-absent line, to get

```
PROMPT='$FG[032]%~/\
$(git_prompt_info)$(hg_prompt_info)\
$FG[105]%(!.#.)%{$reset_color%}'
```

The newline, by the way, was the line break embedded in the value (note there was no `\` at the end of the first line of the original prompt).